# Draws in Quarto

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I was recently introduced to Quarto, a game invented by Swiss mathematician Blaise Muller (which even has its own [**Wikipedia page**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarto_(board_game))).  The conjecture of interest is that there are no draws possible in Quarto, that is, whether every possible game must produce a winning combination [particularly if true, this bears strongly on playing strategies].  On its face, there are 16! (slightly in excess of 20 trillion) different complete game positions possible, although, admittedly, there are many symmetries at play here.

In an attempt to prove/disprove the conjecture, I built a Quarto simulation in MATLAB that was somewhat smart (it pared many branches of the tree early).  After about a week runtime, I called it quits; at that point it had looked at about 2.5 billion game combinations, and found no draws.

So I think I am looking for one of four things:

1. A single counterexample of a complete Quarto board that is a draw.
2. An analytic proof that no draws are possible.
3. A pointer to someplace else where this question has been addressed previously.
4. A strategy for parsing the required search space that is (at a minimum) about four orders of magnitude more efficient than brute force.

Any thoughts or insights?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20041012023358/http://ssel.vub.ac.be/Members/LucGoossens/quarto/quartotext.htm says *...Consequently, if both players play perfectly they will always be able to force a draw.*

Comment: Bingo, now that I am sure a draw exists.  The next obvious question is how rare are they?  Working on that now.

Comment: @Henry - PS - Nice link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly (you're not asking about perfect play),

[image: this]

seems to be a draw.

I got that from [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/is-a-draw-possible-in-quarto-with-the-advanced-rules).

Comment: You understand correctly.  This is interesting.  Thanks.